# Prestashop 1.7.7.5: FrameworkBundleAdminController: $this->module->getPathUri() returns an error

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

In my admin module's controller's `listMappingsAction` action, I want to show a Vue.JS template, passing two variables that need to call `$this->module->getPathUri()` to be assigned a value:

```
<?php
namespace XYZ\Controller;

use PrestaShopBundle\Controller\Admin\FrameworkBundleAdminController;
use PrestaShopBundle\Security\Annotation\AdminSecurity;


class AutomatizedMappingController extends FrameworkBundleAdminController
{

     /**
     * @AdminSecurity("is_granted('read', request.get('_legacy_controller'))", message="Access denied.")
     */
    function listMappingsAction() {
        return  $this->render('@Modules/XYZ/views/templates/admin/app.html.twig', [
            'XYZ' => [
                'pathApp' => $this->module->getPathUri() . 'views/js/app.js',
                'chunkVendor' => $this->module->getPathUri() . 'views/js/chunk-vendors.js',
            ]
        ]);
    }
}
```

The use of `$this->module->getPathUri()` results in this error being displayed:

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "getPathUri" of class "XYZ\Controller\AutomatizedMappingController". [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\UndefinedMethodException 0]

What could I call to make it work? The docs don't mention this use case... https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/templating/vuejs/faq/#how-to-send-data-from-symfony-controller-to-vuejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to know there is a difference between a module and a admin-controller. You cannot call `$this->module->getPathUri()` because your not using a `extends ModuleAdminController`, `extends ModuleFrontController`, `extends Module` ...

So you can only call `$this->module` if your actually using files inside a module.

Since i don't know which path you are trying to go to ill pass you a few variables which you might be able to use.

```
$this->module->name              = crezzurmodulename
$this->module->getLocalPath()    = C:\yourstore/modules/crezzurmodulename/
$this->module->getPathUri()      = /yourstore/modules/crezzurmodulename/
_MODULE_DIR_                     = /yourstore/modules/
_PS_MODULE_DIR_                  = C:\yourstore/modules/
__DIR__                          = C:\yourstore\modules\crezzurmodulename\controllers\front
_PS_CAT_IMG_DIR_                 = C:\yourstore/img/c/
_PS_PROD_IMG_DIR_                = C:\yourstore/img/p/
_PS_TMP_IMG_DIR_                 = C:\yourstore/img/tmp/
_PS_ROOT_DIR_                    = C:\yourstore
_PS_CACHE_DIR_                   = C:\yourstore/var/cache/dev\
_PS_BASE_URL_                    = http://127.0.0.1
__PS_BASE_URI__                  = /yourstore/
_PS_TRANSLATIONS_DIR_            = C:\yourstore/translations/
_PS_BASE_URL_SSL_                = http://127.0.0.1 or https://127.0.0.1
_PS_DOWNLOAD_DIR_                = C:\yourstore/download/
_PS_COL_IMG_DIR_                 = C:\yourstore/img/co/
_PS_SHIP_IMG_DIR_                = C:\yourstore/img/s/
_PS_UPLOAD_DIR_                  = C:\yourstore/upload/
```

Comment: "First of all you need to know there is a difference between a module and a admin-controller. " : according to https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/controllers/admin-controllers/#how-to-declare-a-new-controller : "Somewhere **in your module** declare a new class that will act as a Controller:" and they show a `FrameworkBundleAdminController`. So I think rather that `FrameworkBundleAdminController` is the new way to declare a module controller. Am I wrong?

Comment: Hello, you are correct, i am sorry. I keep working as long as possible using the old way, because for now they still work for the old and new PS versions. (reach more people with same module) but like stated here `https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/controllers/admin-controllers/override-decorate-controller/` you are doing it right but for now i must apology not sure why `$this->module->name`  doesn't work then

Comment: I researched a bit further and you can also call it like this `Module::getInstanceByName('yourmodulename')->getPathUri();`ill keep looking until i find the solution :D

Comment: Np :)
`PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Adapter\Module\Module`?

Comment: `module:XYZ/views/js/chunk-vendors.js` seems to work well. However now I have a blank page instead of the error I've shown in the OP. But this is out of topic.

The **real** problem is: PS 1.7 docs are not fully updated...there are plenty of errors in their docs...

Comment: Just had a look into the PS modules and the module `modules\ps_linklist\src\Controller\Admin\Improve\Design\LinkBlockController.php` uses the controller, maybe you can find some idea's there